# Disable click for sunburst or treemap chart with trace, configuration or layout?

Tags: plotly.js

In plotly.js, I'm trying to disable the animation for a treemap when you click on one of the squares. In my app, there's only one level of parents, so zooming in on a specific square isn't very helpful. I saw a similar question here: https://community.plot.ly/t/sorting-slices-in-sunburst-and-disabling-animations/27558 .

Is there a way I can set this in the trace or configuration instead?

Answer (score 1):

You can disable such interaction in a treemap by falsifying the plotly_treemapclick event.

```
Plotly.newPlot('graph', [{
  type: 'treemap',
  labels: ['Root', 'A', 'B', 'a', 'aa', 'b', 'bb'],
  parents: ['', 'Root', 'Root', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B']
}])
.then(gd => {
  gd.on('plotly_treemapclick', () => false)
})
```